# Error in paste0(.prefix, subclass) : el argumento "subclass" está ausente, sin valor por omisión

Tags: r

No entiendo muy bien el error que me arroja R:

> Error in paste0(.prefix, subclass) : el argumento "subclass" está ausente, sin valor por omisión

```r
 formula <- MONTO_FRAUDE ~ .
    
    'modelo_STEPWISE <- step(
      object    = lm(formula, data = datos_entrenamiento),
      direction = "backward",
      scope     = list(upper = ~., lower = ~1),
      trace     = FALSE
    )'
```

Me arroja un error la fórmula que no sé corregir para hacer un modelo stepwise.

Comment: No puedo reproducir el error. La primera línea genera un objeto de la clases fórmula y le asigna el nombre `formula`. La segunda genera un vector de caracteres válido de largo 1.